# How Do I Move a Card to a New List Using Trello REST API?

Tags: python, rest, request, put, trello

I'm using Python to interact with Trello via its REST api. I can GET from Trello fine. However, I want to move a card to a different list, but I can't get the request to stick.

My url is: `https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[card_id]/[list_id]?key=[api_key]&token=[token]`

I've tried calling it like this:

```
import requests
requests.put(url)
```

and this

```
import requests
requests.put(url, {"method": "put"})
```

and

```
from urllib.requests import Request
Request(url, method="PUT")
```

But I get a 404 error for the first two and nothing for the third. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Do you know?

Answer (score 2):

After hunting around the code from the python trello api pip install package (https://pythonhosted.org/trello/index.html), it seems like I have to do it like this:

```
 import requests
 requests.put(https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[card_id], 
              params=dict(key=self._key, token=self._token), 
              data=dict(idList=listID))
```

Note that to move across boards, you need to provide the board ID as well:

```
 requests.put(https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[card_id], 
              params=dict(key=self._key, token=self._token), 
              data=dict(idList=listID, idBoard=boardID))
```

This works for me, hope it does for you too!